# How to dynamically change pictures of each ngfor element

Tags: angular

So imagine it as a social media feed just similar to instagram.

I got ngfor loop to show the products, the product can have up to 10 images, I've added the images to each product by pulling it from the database the images are stored in an array called picUrls, I just loop through them like this for example

`[src]="product.picUrls[picindex]"`

then when you click right on the image of the product or left we have this function

`goRight(index){ ... }`

this works perfectly. The only problem I face is, the pictures change for all the products, say you goRight on product 1, it also goes right on product 2 meaning it switches pictures. How do I bind this to change pictures only on one product?

I am perfectly aware of the issue, the picindex is a global value and it changes for every element, but how do I go about this I can't seem to figure it out. I can't bind the index of the actual product because there is no condition on the image.

Comment: Just create a map to store each index for each product .
Something along these lines :  {[productId]: number} , and always pass the product id when switching pictures, and use it to get the current index